# Admob test vs real ads

Tags: ios, xcode, admob, ads

Just a quick question it's normal to see test ads in the simulator/real device, but not real live ads? I didn't get any email of a violation or anything and i waited for 2 days or so and I can't see real live ads on simulator/real device, I was just wondering if I didn't see them because of the Admob policy they only let you to see test ads.(first time using admob)

**EDIT**

Made to be above tableView:

```
var googleAd: GADBannerView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        googleAd = GADBannerView(adSize: kGADAdSizeSmartBannerPortrait)
        self.view.addSubview(googleAd)
        googleAd.adUnitID = "I check this already. It's all good"
        googleAd.rootViewController = self
        googleAd.delegate = self
        googleAd.load(GADRequest())
        let request:GADRequest = GADRequest()
        request.testDevices = [kGADSimulatorID]
        googleAd.load(request)

        googleAd.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        googleAd.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        googleAd.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        googleAd.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.widthAnchor).isActive = true
        googleAd.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
}
```

I also set the `GADBannerViewDelegate` too

Comment: If you have enabled your real admob id you should see also real ads. Check your Code.

Comment: @mrkernelpanic do you mind seeing the edit. I check it should be working fine. By the way I disable the `request.testDevices` before posting this. I thought by disabling it the real live ad would work.

Comment: @mrkernelpanic if I send it to the app store will the live ads work?